# Best Practices For Downloading Entire FTP Site to Local Network Drive (VB.NET)

Tags: .net, ftp

I am writing a service to download and then delete the entire contents of a FTP site each weekend.

The files range from 2mb to 8mb in size and the initial download is about 150,000+. After this, I expect the download range to be 2000 files weekly. I plan on scheduling the service to run each weekend around midnight.

This is for one vendor, if everything works out then we will be doing this with hundreds of vendors on a weekly basis.

I'm interested in best practices for writing a reliable service, capable of downloading such a large volume of files.

Some questions/concerns:

1. Handling exceptions and timeout issues.
2. Properly deleting empty folders after the all the file contents are removed
3. How to make sure no one started uploading to a folder we're about to delete.
4. Should I consider spiting the tasks into separate services?

   - Service #1
     parses the directory contents and saves the file name to a table.
   - Service # 2 downloads and deletes file and if the directory is empty, deletes the folder .

I'm just throwing some ideas out there; not asking anyone to write me anything. Just looking for ideas on how to architect something like this.

```
Private Function GetStringResponse(ByVal ftp As FtpWebRequest) As String

            Dim response As FtpWebResponse = Nothing
            Dim datastream As Stream = Nothing
            Dim sr As StreamReader = Nothing
            Dim result As String = ""

            Try

                response = DirectCast(ftp.GetResponse, FtpWebResponse)

                Dim size As Long = response.ContentLength

                datastream = response.GetResponseStream

                sr = New StreamReader(datastream)

                result = sr.ReadToEnd()

            Finally
                If Not response Is Nothing Then
                    response.Close()
                End If
                If Not datastream Is Nothing Then
                    datastream.Close()
                End If
                If Not sr Is Nothing Then
                    sr.Close()
                End If

            End Try

            Return result

End Function


 Private Function GetRequest(ByVal URI As String, Optional p_KeepAlive As Boolean = False) As FtpWebRequest

            Dim result As FtpWebRequest = CType(FtpWebRequest.Create(URI), FtpWebRequest)
            If m_UserSsl Then
                Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = AddressOf ValidateCertificate
                result.EnableSsl = True
            End If


            result.Credentials = GetCredentials()

            result.KeepAlive = p_KeepAlive

            Return result

End Function


        Public Function GetDirectoryTree(p_Directory As String, Optional p_Mask As String = "") As List(Of String)

            Dim files As New List(Of String)
            Dim folders As New Queue(Of String)()
            Dim _resp As StreamReader = Nothing
            Dim _Ftp As Net.FtpWebRequest = Nothing

            folders.Enqueue(p_Directory)

            While folders.Count > 0
                Dim fld As String = folders.Dequeue()
                Dim newFiles As List(Of String)

                _Ftp = GetRequest(GetDirectory(fld), True)
                _Ftp.Method = Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory

                Dim response As String = GetStringResponse(_Ftp)

                If response.Length > 0 Then
                    newFiles = response.Replace(Convert.ToChar(13) + Convert.ToChar(10), Convert.ToChar(13)).TrimEnd(Convert.ToChar(13)).Split(Convert.ToChar(13)).ToList()
                    If p_Mask <> String.Empty Then newFiles = newFiles.Where(Function(x) x.ToUpper Like p_Mask.ToUpper).ToList
                Else
                    newFiles = New List(Of String)
                End If

                _Ftp = GetRequest(GetDirectory(fld), True)
                _Ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails

                Using resp As New StreamReader(_Ftp.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
                    Dim line As String = resp.ReadLine()
                    While line IsNot Nothing
                        If line.Trim().ToLower().StartsWith("d") OrElse line.Contains(" <DIR> ") Then
                            Dim dir As String = newFiles.First(Function(x) line.EndsWith(x))
                            newFiles.Remove(dir)
                            folders.Enqueue(fld + dir + "/")
                        End If
                        line = resp.ReadLine()
                    End While
                End Using

                files.AddRange(newFiles.Select(Function(x) fld + x).ToList())
            End While

End Function
```

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: I don't have much of the code written yet. Just trying to not paint myself into a corner. I updated the post with the directory parser code I wrote for testing.

Comment: @user1932634 Hmm... Are you user3541092?

Comment: Yes, I must have logged in using my work gmail account... Can the question be transferred to my active account (user1932634)?